# Rails and ActionCable. Several environments with one redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have bunch of apps: `my.com`, `a.my.com`, `b.my.com`, ..

All of them use one redis server with different databases `url: redis://localhost:6379/1`, `url: redis://localhost:6379/2`, ..

But broadcast messages go to every app. That's because of https://redis.io/topics/pubsub:

> Pub/Sub has no relation to the key space. It was made to not interfere with it on any level, including database numbers.
>   Publishing on db 10, will be heard by a subscriber on db 1.
>   If you need scoping of some kind, prefix the channels with the name of the environment

There was the same issue in Rails repository https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27224.

I see only several options:

1. Use separate redis server for each app
2. Somehow prefix `steam_from` in `#subscribed`: `stream_from("#{some_config.or_env.channel_prefix}_#{user.id}")`
3. Use another provider (not Redis)

Am I missing something? Is there a better and easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I missed that part about [channel_prefix](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/action_cable_overview.md#redis-adapter). When we migrate to 5.1 we'll use this feature.